# Запятая после "ну"

Tags: пунктуация

"— И после этого вы еще на что-то надеетесь?
— Ну(,) а вдруг?"
Интонационно паузы после "ну" нет, но перед "а", вроде как, должна быть запятая. Как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частица "ну" запятой не отделяется. А кто сказал, что перед "А" всегда нужна запятая? Вовсе нет. Только при наличии условий: например между частями сложного предложения, между однородными членами.